# Transforming a hash object in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Curious to know the best way to do this in ruby. I have done it but think Im not doing the best

I have a hash object as follows

```
{2=>{:name=>"Somename"}, 3=>{:last_name=>"Something"}}
```

I want to get to

```
{:name=>"Somename",:last_name=>"Something"}
```

Comment: you mean [{:name=>"Somename"},{:last_name=>"Something"}]?

Comment: I can't read the original solution, but it seems like you're converting symbols to symbols, and strings to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input_hash.values.reduce { |h,v| h.merge(v) }
```

UPDATE: I thought that my answer is shortest but I was wrong, the answer from **tokland**:

```
input_hash.values.reduce(:merge)
```

Comment: +1; that's what I was looking for. Although I'd use something other than `h` as the block parameter to avoid any cognitive overhead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the input value

Comment: yup, thx all, Dave yr way also worked, this is nice and clean. cheers gents

Comment: also known as `input_hash.values.reduce(:merge)`

Answer (score 1):

### Use the Splat Operator

In this particular case, you can extract the values of your hash into an array of hashes with the splat operator. For example:

```
my_hash = {2=>{:name=>"Somename"}, 3=>{:last_name=>"Something"}}
[*my_hash.values]
# => [{:name=>"Somename"}, {:last_name=>"Something"}]
```

Comment: doesn't it the same as `my_hash.values`? yes, it is

Comment: @NARKOZ is right. `my_hash.values` gives you an array. The splat converts this to a list of arguments, which are used to rebuild the same array (with `[]`).